# Answering a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was reading a lot here about duplicates on SO, but I'm still confused what should I, and what can an asking person do.

Here is a situation:

1. I visit newly asked question, that I judge I can answer,
2. it turns out to be a duplicate of my own answer,
3. in a comment, I leave a link with my answer posted in the past,
4. I flag a new question so more experienced users can manage that,
5. **a person who asked a duplicate suggests to leave an answer, so he/she can accept it**.

So I'm confused if I should post a duplicate of my own answer, or is it a moment I should end my interaction? On the other side - what can that person do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question should be closed as a duplicate.  You should use the appropriate type of flag to propose the duplicate, and if it really is a duplicate, hopefully it will be closed as such reasonably quickly.

The answer from the duplicate should not be duplicated as an answer here, even if the OP asks you to.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. I voted to close and linked the answer in the comments. I asked OP to upvote my answer if found helpful .