# Is it wrong to downvote a good answer to a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So here is a [duplicate question with a decent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494845/replacing-if-with-loops). Is it wrong to downvote the answer because the answer-er should have searched for duplicates before answering? I personally don't think so. If it's been answered already, it adds no value to SO. I was just wondering where the community stands on downvoting good answers to duplicate questions. Am I wrong to do so? If so, what else could I do to discourage people from answering a pretty obvious duplicate? I probably could have found at least ten other already answered questions on this topic.

I do not believe that this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252047/answering-a-duplicate). I am specifically questioning the ethicality of downvoting an answer to a duplicate question in order to discourage the answering of dupes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh the irony....

Comment: Compare the answer to the linked question to the answers to the duplicate.  It really isn't that good.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg No, but it's not *bad* either. That's kind of beside the point though.

Comment: The same was brought up on a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496954/comparing-string-with-its-reference-by) just now, so I'll restate my comment: *Quick oneliners on obvious duplicates are not remotely near the quality of the answers in the "main" question. It reinforces the habit of new users to ask a question before looking anything up. These are bad answers.*. You can expand the "quick oneliners" to anything that isn't on par with the quality of the linked answers.

Comment: [Should we downvote answers to obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions) also related (and the answer applies): [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions?lq=1)

Comment: I don't think the responsibility for finding duplicates should be the answerers responsibility. I may know something off the top of my head, how am I to know someone has already answered this subject? I don't need to do research for my answer, so how will I ever find out about this?

Comment: @OGHaza finds duplicate to my question (thankfully it's on Meta Exchange). Thank you for sharing those. It looks like there's a reasonable amount of debate on the topic.

Comment: @Joe How is it not our responsibility to check for duplicates before answering a question if we care about duplicates as a community?

Comment: @ckuhn203, I didn't downvote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494845/replacing-if-with-loops/23495003#23495003), but personally it doesn't actually answers the Q and this asnwer is a very low quality. If OP wants to delete rows, they should use _revers_ loop in opposite to `For Each row In rng.Rows` (and author didn't mention about this) and also if you delete row in this loop, nested loop would fails at some point `For Each cell in row.Cells`

Comment: and also why do you think this answer was downvoted _because Q was duplicate_? My opinion - this A was downvoted because of it's low quality.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: could you please point me where exactly the question "Is it wrong to downvote a good answer to a duplicate question?" is answered in the link that you claim to be a duplicate?

Comment: @simoco I'm asking because my gut tells me that answering duplicate questions should be discouraged. We have little recourse to discourage people from answering duplicate questions besides downvoting the answer. But, on the flip side of it, it doesn't feel right to downvote a good answer either. (I've noted elsewhere that this isn't a great example, just the one that prompted the thought).

Comment: It is a "possible" duplicate @J.F.Sebastian and was more intended toungue-in-cheek.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: ok. I'm tired of people that vote to close a question as a duplicate without understanding the question so it is not funny to me.

Comment: My apologies @J.F.Sebastian. I totally understood the question and should have been clearer about my intent. The irony is that a duplicate was found and listed later in the comments.

Comment: Some people are trying very hard to learn the code, so they ask the community in order to gain knowledge of what they're doing wrong.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use: they would do better to learn to ask better questions.

Comment: I'd say, on a *good* answer, yes it's wrong, but *good* is subjective, therefore what you see as a *good* answer may look like a *poor* answer to someone else, ignoring whether or not the answer is correct. Obviously if it is incorrect it should be downvoted.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Whether something is a duplicate is often a matter of judgment.  I've seen a number of cases where a question which differed slightly from another, and merited an answer addressing its unique aspect, got merged and where, as a consequence, the answer was no longer relevant to the question to which it got moved; sometimes dupe-merging is helpful, but if questions have aspects that don't overlap, being able to address those areas would also be helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I feel it is the asker's responsibility to search for duplicates.  Downvote the question, but upvote the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 32):

I disagree: if the answer is good and it's not clearly copy-pasted or slightly "refactored" from the answers linked on the post (or posted by others) it adds value to the post and unless a "posts-merging" is taken into consideration by someone, it shouldn't be downvoted in my opinion.

If it adds no value to the original post (but still: it's not a simple copy-paste) it doesn't necessarily mean that the author wanted to just farm reputation: it's not always immediate to find duplicates for a specific question.

---

**And now for the real experiment**: how many people will downvote my answer although there's already a duplicate for your question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252047/answering-a-duplicate) (that I saw later after posting the above)?

Comment: IMO, it doesn't deserve anything so I don't vote (as demonstrated with your answer :P )

Comment: @marco 1. Votes on meta tend to reflect agreement/disagreement more than quality of answer. 2. It's not a duplicate. I'm asking about the ethicality of downvoting an answer to a duplicate question to discourage the answering of such questions.

Comment: @ckuhn203 1. That's why it's an experiment. I agree that the question is not really a duplicate, but I couldn't resist the opportunity of throwing this small test

Comment: @marco So perhaps that particular example is not the greatest one, but what about the principal of it?

Comment: sorry not following you.. the principal of what?

Comment: Of downvoting an answer because it answers a duplicate question to discourage the answering of duplicates.

Comment: Oh god..... I'm talking in circles.

Comment: yes it's kind of a contrived topic I see! Anyway I don't really see the big problem in having an answer which is equally good to the accepted one. In the worst case it will save the user a link-click and a page reload, in the good case the user might want to dig more (like Google's second page of results which usually feels kind of lonely..) in the original post if the solution doesn't really fit for him. Notice that the quality of the answer must hold, otherwise downvoting is righteously.

Comment: the issue as your answer (perhaps intentionally) demonstrates is that the question that is designated as a duplicate is not a real duplicate . And it would be doubly wrong to downvote a valid answer.

Answer (score 12):

I believe that it is easiest to always point duplicates back to the original. When this is the case, all of the information about a single question will be in a single place.

For people who think it is alright to answer a duplicate question with a non C&P (or rewritten answer), I disagree. If you have additional knowledge that can help a duplicate question, that should also be posted on the original.

Therefore, in terms of *any* voting on an answer on a duplicate question, even if it is high quality, I disagree with.

Comment: the question is about a *downvote*. An upvote is not considered.

Comment: I will rephrase my post. I meant to come to the conclusion that no voting should occur; Down or up. @J.F.Sebastian

Answer (score 4):

Saw this blog post on [Improved Question Merging](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/) from 2010 — is this still accurate?

> Our kinder, gentler question merge has none of these
> problems! It behaves much more like a typical duplicate close, with
> the exception that the **answers are migrated to the target question**.

I'd thought that an exact duplicate could be merged with the original to migrate the answers? In that case, there would be no issue where the good answer is originally posted, just need to ask a mod to merge them together.

Comment: If this works, I'd **love** it to be used more and the answers de-duped.

Comment: Question merging is often unfeasible because two questions that are conceptually identical will have different code blocks for their MREs (which may or may not be particularly M), and people will write answers that *heavily reference the code in the question they're written on*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel even so, I'd still agree with what I posted 8 years ago — IMO, it'd be better to auto-merge & put the good answer on the canonical question, rather than downvoting the answer just because it's on a duplicate question. If it is so specific to the MRE that it starts getting downvotes when migrated, I don't really see a problem? That's the system working as intended & prompting the answerer (or another user) to clean up the answer for its new home, or delete it if it's surpllus to requirements.