# How to deal appropriately with answers posted for obvious help vampire questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

Today I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553451/c-coding-issue)

[image]

that obviously didn't deserve to get an answer, in preserving from getting future researchers the impression, such questions are well formed, and achieved at SO well.
Though there was an answer given by a (very) high rep user, where I thought these should know better, not to answer such question because of the above mentioned reasons:

[image]

<sub>Please forgive those low resolution screenshots, but I couldn't find a better way to provide <10K users with the stuff in question, because the question is actually deleted now.</sub>

How should we handle such answers appearing? I've actually downvoted it (and marked for deletion later on).
IMHO such answer (though being correct, and pointing out the stuff necessary to solve), or even a comment in that direction would be wrong, since the question is unwanted at SO, and any different reaction might encourage the actual OP, or future researchers, that they will receive answers for asking inappropriate questions.

I have noticed the answerer about this, and of course used all of my available powers, to downvote the question and the answer, and to close- and delete vote that question.
The question is deleted now, but already has `undelete()` votes casted on it.

My primary concern about this is:

**Did I act right here?** (Usually I'm not downvoting for correct answers, but in this case giving an answer at all seemed to be inappropriate for me).

Sorry for raising the drama, but the answerer of the question themselves proposed I should raise it here for clarification.
I think the question won't fit well for SO policies and should have been closed in 1st place instead of receiving an answer (or even comment). Mostly because I'm  concerned this would give a completely wrong bias for the OP or future researchers, and leave the impression, that such kind of questions may be asked on SO, and get some useful answer.

IMHO, we don't need any Igors (or Vlads to refer another meme) to serve the help vampires.

Comment: _that obviously didn't deserve to get an answer_ why? Who decided that? Every question deserve an answer, doesn't matter if the question's quality is low. I don't know what is a _vampire question_ actually, your question is like OP is an enemy and trying to us writing codes. Even a question is not clear and with low quality, still deserve an answer unluess you think answerers are doing that only for rep.

Comment: @GLHF I've made up my points about that. I'm interested and engaged that the long term quality of the site is kept up. _"Every question deserve an answer, doesn't matter if the question's quality is low."_ I strongly disagree: Not every question deserves an answer (that's why we have policies setup for off-topic questions)

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) somewhat related

Comment: @Krishnabhadra _"Somewhat"_ yes.

Comment: The question is too broad, not researched, and entirely fulfils the old "too localised" close reason. It is decidedly not useful for any future reader, unless they come here with the exact same problem and actually know how to search. I'm on the fence about answering questions like this because on one hand I like to help - but on the other hand, quality must be maintained above quantity or we become Yahoo Answers. Answering questions like these only encourages help vampires to continue asking. As for what to do... well. You're well within your rights to downvote, as that's your own business.

Comment: @J.Steen Well, I supposed all of that regarding the question being true beforehand. _"Answering questions like these only encourages help vampires to continue asking."_ That well hits that same nail I'm trying to hammer on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah. That comment was mostly for the benefit of those advocating answering all questions because all questions are useful. I'm agreeing with you, and disagreeing with that point. ;)

Comment: It's merely "Too Broad."  Vote to close and delete accordingly.  Answerers don't earn rep from deleted questions.

Comment: AFAIK, the very first definition of "help vampires" is when they are asking questions/clarifications *repeatedly* without even trying. While I agree that question should be closed, I humbly disagree with the premise of the title. The case that the OP is "help vampire" is not yet proven.

Comment: @AndrewT. Why should we wait for the 2nd bite, before eliminating the vampire? See [member for today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4573901/jason-lutes), it just goes [from dusk till dawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dusk_till_Dawn) And even worse, they're approaching here with a massive front recently. We need professional consults like Van Helsing to manage this, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's a shame to see paxdiablo, who I generally respect, falling into the "SO hates beginners" trap. It's nonsense. It is possible to be a beginner and ask an on-topic, appropriate question. Pointing out that a beginner has _not_ done so is not the same as rejecting beginners.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm tempted to dispute your premise here, debate the whole "answering no-effort questions causes others unwilling to put in any effort to ask more no-effort questions" idea... But that's a much longer, thornier discussion and in this case completely unnecessary.

See, you just admitted to downvoting an answer that you saw as correct and useful. You defend this with some highfalutin language about the good of the site, but the ends don't justify the means; you're still not voting based on *the content of the post*. Once you start rationalizing that, where do you stop? Do you downvote their answers to *other* questions too? Upvote answers to questions you feel are worthy, regardless of whether they're accurate?

And maybe *you* wouldn't take it any further than you have, but you're setting an example for others too. Especially when you start publicly chastising the answerer in comments. Is *this* what you want to be teaching new users?

Poorly-asked questions **are** a problem. *Primarily* because they tend to attract poor answers. If you're just now facing this quandary after almost 3 years on Stack Overflow, it's probably *because* it's so rare to find a good answer to an awful question. Heck, [Reversal is one of the most rare badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) - **you might as well be asking if you should shoot unicorns to protect against over-grazing.**

Vote based on content. If you see a crappy question, downvote it. If you see a crappy answer, downvote it. If you see a crappy answer to a crappy question, downvote both. And when you see a good, useful post - even in an unlikely location - upvote it. And stop worrying about unicorns.

Comment: "See, you just admitted to downvoting an answer that you saw as correct and useful" - I think you should distinguisih between "correct" and "useful" here; OP downvoted the _correct_ answer because they think it's _not useful_ - as in, not useful to the community as a whole or anybody else than the guy who asked the bad "do my homework please" question.

Comment: @l4mpi - That is a misinterpretation of the phrasing "useful". You have taken it out of context.

Comment: _you might as well be asking if you should shoot unicorns to protect against over-grazing_ - that's classy. I might not even have had to type up my own answer, really :)

Comment: OK. I dig it. ------

Comment: As far as debating the core issue of whether answering bad questions hurts the site, I've had a few things to say about that before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions/255805#255805 . (TLDR: No, I don't think providing good answers to bad questions leads to more of them being asked.)

Comment: Let's be clear that the specific post under discussion isn't a correct answer; there is no "correct", or even "answer", because there's no question. This is an advertisement requesting mentoring. (Which is, as has been said other places, a perfectly natural thing to need, but won't fit on SO.)

Comment: I don't think anyone is defending the question here, @Josh. The answer, OTOH, was pretty solid - I wish we could auto-reply with something like that every time someone typed "Write a program that" into the question editor.

Comment: It's true; paxdiablo's post is a nice piece of pedagogy and it does seem a shame to raise such a ruckus about it.

Answer (score 11):

Dare to say that Stack Overflow isn't a help website but a knowledge base in Q&A format. If you don't tell them they'll assume it's a help website because that's what they want.

Comment: Stating that SO is a knowledge base, not a help website, isn't going to help since they don't know the difference and will assume it's still something that is supposed to be helpful.  Any attempt to dismiss someone genuinely seeking guidance without providing it is a disservice to the SO community.  Just because a question has no value to you doesn't mean the person asking it has no value.

Comment: @CandiedOrange just because a question has value to one single person doesn't mean it shouldn't be deleted, or should be answered. And please elaborate why telling people to adhere to SOs standards or GTFO if they don't read through the help center or lurk for a while before asking their first question is "a disservice to the SO community". I'd say answering their question without educating them about the expected SO standards is the disservice to the community; as teaching them how to ask a good question should take preference over answering their low-quality, heavily localized question.

Comment: @l4mpi Please reread my comment.  You are thrusting a position upon me that I did not take.

Answer (score 8):

"Eliminating the vampire" is not the goal.

Encouraging quality content is.¹

> Upvote good content, downvote bad content.

**If the answer is not bad, you can't downvote it**. Period. As soon as we do that we're in the realm of political downvoting, and potentially punishing people for well-meaning contribution.

If someone bothers to answer bad question, their loss. Just don't upvote it - as luck will have it it will soon drop of the frontpage when the answer reaches -3 and no one will spot the answer.

If this is not working well enough yet, maybe the post ranking algorithm should be altered to weigh *question downvotes* heavier than mere *activity*.

If well implemented, we'll see people learning not to answer low-quality questions *iff* rep is their motivation. If not? Bless them! It's *their* time.

---

¹ Eliminating vampire posts is, by extension, a subgoal. Note the difference between a perceived need to chase away "bad individuals". That's not necessary to serve a community by rewarding good content and discouraging bad content.

Comment: "If the answer is not bad, you can't downvote it" - the downvote arrow doesn't talk about _bad_ or _good_ but about _not useful_. One can certainly say a good answer to an awful, extremely localized, unresearched question is not useful at all. From a cleanup perspective, it's detrimental as well - should the answer get upvoted, it will prevent the roomba from deleting the question after it's closed as "too broad".

Comment: @l4mpi - One could say a spectacular answer is not useful, but they would be incorrect. I agree with the premise of this answer.

Comment: @TravisJ "useful" depends on context. Useful to whom? Definitely not to me or you or anybody who already has basic programming knowledge. My point is, the answer may be useful to a small amount of users (who fall outside of SOs target group of _professional and enthusiast programmers_ anyways), but can still be considered not useful for the site as a whole. As an example, a spectacular answer explaining how to write hello world in basic, posted on a low-quality question that is downvoted and deleted, is not useful at all.

Comment: And given that [a mod recommends closure and deltion of the question under discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286230/how-to-deal-appropriately-with-answers-posted-for-obvious-help-vampire-questions#comment155991_286230), I'd say no answer to this question can ever be useful to the community - it's going to be deleted anyways!

Comment: Talk about circular reasoning. You're referring to the usefulness after potential deletion.

Comment: @sehe I'm basically saying _one should not answer posts which should be deleted_. How is that circular reasoning?

Comment: I take it you forget about the part where you were citing this effective uselessness as a reason to downvote the answer. That's what makes it circular. The point of my answer is that the uselessness of the question should already discourage the answer enough. But @Shog9 put the point much more poetically :)

Comment: The usefulness is separate from the deletion. One can post an high-quality answer on how to add two numbers in python, which is still completely useless to anybody who ever has done any programming. Also, "The point of my answer is that the uselessness of the question should already discourage the answer enough" - Well, as evident by the question linked by OP, _it doesn't_. And it's not like that's a singular occurrence; I see it all day every day in the python and java tags. OP asks what should be done when the answerer is _not_ discouraged and continues to post an answer to a bad question.

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah. "What can we do" - throw up hands in despair - whatever shall we do, now that the end of the world is nigh. Well, like 90% of the drivel on the site, we downvote the bad posts and let history handle itself. _(In fact the majority of those unwarranted answers are themselves bad, so you can have ball and downvote them. I don't see the problem.)_ No need to stretch logic because of /fear/

Comment: @sehe Note I'm neither in despair nor fear for the end of the world. I am however under the impression that answering low-level crap questions, no matter how good the answer, is at the end of the day a wasted effort at best and actively detrimental to the site quality at worst. Resorting to sarcasm in response to that just feels like you're out of logical arguments.

Comment: Just don't upvote answers to bad questions?  If someone posts a good answer to a bad question the thing to do is upvote the answer and edit the question.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253758/1493294

Comment: @l4mpi Seems to me you're fabricating reasons to downvote good posts. And the only reason I can smell is "fear". That's exactly as good an argument as you are making. ("that just feels like you're out of logical arguments"). My statement is that it's _not an issue_ to have useless posts. Besides there is nothing you can do stop people from wasting their time. _(Some people will waste their time arguing in comment threads.)_

Comment: @sehe Your _opinion_ is that it's not an issue to have useless posts. My _experience_ is that people who get their crap answered, and way too often _without even being told why their question is bad_, often proceed to ask more of the same useless crap questions. I rarely see high rep users taking time time to educate users about SO, instead of just writing an answer. Also, why are you focused on votes? I don't care if the answer is downvoted or not, I'm saying _it should not be posted in the first place_; and certainly not without telling OP how and why their question is a bad fit for SO.

Comment: _"If the answer is not bad, you can't downvote it. Period."_ Well that's just nonsense for a start!! To my annoyance, it's been pointed out to me many times on the metas that people can downvote for whatever reason they damn well please. Period.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's funny, because you're the one who attuned me to the notion that political downvoting exists, and shouldn't be encouraged. IMO this question is exactly about this: downvoting answers only because the question is bad _is_ political downvoting

Comment: @l4mpi I'm focused on the votes because that was the (a) topic of this question. As for the rest, LRIO's realism applies: people do as they damn well please... so "shouldn't be posted" is not constructive. It's whiny, "mom! they're doing naughty things" mode, when there are perfectly good controls in place. No one stops you from commenting at these answers. I do that. And I'm **happy** to downvote crappy answers.

Comment: FTR. I never said it's not a problem to have useless posts. I _said_ the fact that a good answer has little use on a bad question is not a problem in my book.

Comment: I did say what would be constructive: educating the user about SO and closing and deleting their question. And I do question the "perfectly good controls" - if they're so perfect, why are we overrun with idiots who are unable to do even the most basic programming tasks? As I said, _answering_ these kinds of questions, which happens way too often, is IMO a huge factor. And of course people do as they please, _unless there is something in place to deter them from doing so_ - you assume we can't or shouldn't change the status quo and e.g. punish users answering too many closed/deleted questions.

Comment: @sehe: Oh, I absolutely discourage it (see my answer!). I'm just saying that to indicate that one "can't" is false. :) Man, I _wish_!

Comment: "why are we overrun with idiots" - the only answer there is that there are too many individuals who just will not give a damn/comprehend. Or they're so desperate that they'll go on anyway. "If it's possible to build dikes, why do we still have floods?" "If we can kill ants with poison/lure them away, why do they still keep coming"?

Comment: @sehe following your analogy, I'm saying that _feeding the ants_ is a bad idea and should be discouraged and is a definite cause why ants come back. And thusly, maybe some things should be implemented that punishes people who feed ants, instead of poisoning them or even better attempting to turn them from an ant into a butterfly by educating them about our ways (which requires more effort than writing an answer (genetic engineering? the analogy breaks down here a bit) but is definitely possible for a percentage of the ants).

Comment: @l4mpi And my point is you don't hit people who eat their sandwhich at the wrong side of the park with clubs _because they might leave crumbs that feed ants_. I'd rather have something in place to "punish" entitled people who think they can preempt each and any human behaviour, and in doing so don't hesitate to punish contributions just because they think it might have an adverse effect¹. Then again, Meta.SO might be exactly that :/ _(¹ I see little or no historical evidence that it would even have an effect. See [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286236/85371))_

Comment: @l4mpi Re: constructiveness: you entered that rather late. Do you wish to remove your comments in relation to downvoting/punishing? I'm all in favour of educating the OP. I do it all the time. And it works, often. However, downvoting good answers is like poisoning the humans because poisoning the ants didn't work out.

Comment: @l4mpi - Do you really think that sehe merely has opinions while you have experience?

Comment: @TravisJ if all you have to contribute to this debate are short trollish comments you might as well stay silent. And please don't put words in my mouth, I never said sehe has no experience, but that _one specific statement he made was an opinion (based on his experience, I assume) which directly contradicts my personal experience_. That can of course be caused by a number of reasons, starting with the fact that the C++ tag is probably vastly different from the python and java tags and thus we experience the site in different ways.

Comment: @l4mpi - I have nothing to say because I am not arguing against the points made here. I believe they are accurate. It is your retorts I find primarily opinion based and lacking in any sort of factual support other than what you cite as experience. You are the one making broad claims and therefore you are the one with the burden of proof. Please provide *any* shred of evidence towards your claims aside from "trust me, I have seen it".

Comment: @l4mpi - Perhaps you should trust more in people who have looked at all angles of these issues internally such as [Shog9's answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286236/1026459) and Brad Larson's answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255805/1026459 speaking to the issue of answering bad questions.

Comment: @TravisJ oh, you mean you've never come across a user that just continues to ask crap questions because they are all answered no matter how bad they are? How about [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283365/1110381) who admits to creating multiple accounts and getting all of them questionbanned by asking crap - do you really think people would do that if they would not get answers? Yes, Brad rightly says that you can never stop _all_ of the crap, but answering everything just encourages people like the guy I linked, who is certainly not alone in this behaviour.

Comment: @l4mpi - You mean the guy who had all of his accounts blocked? See, that is what happens. The system takes out the *asker*, not the answerer.  Stop using some sort of vigilante justice to attack answerers because of poor questions. Stopping answers only leads to less answers, not less questions.

Comment: @TravisJ "Stopping answers only leads to less answers, not less questions" - and that's the point where _you_ are making broad claims without any evidence, or worse, in denial of my evidence. Of course the user got all their acounts banned, but only _after_ flooding SO with bad questions (and they probably made new ones already). So please provide _any_ shred of evidence towards your claims aside from "trust me, that's how it is".

Comment: @l4mpi - You can re-read the links I provide which cite Shog and Brad Larson who have a lot of credibility towards this issue. I also do not find it hard to believe that stopping answers leads to less answers. That seems rather straight forward. Addressing answers to solve question quality is an XY problem. This is why the entirety of work being done to improve question quality is aimed at the *asker*, not the answerer.

Comment: @TravisJ neither of those answers contain any hard facts contradicting my claim. I also don't find it hard to believe that people would ask less bad questions if bad questions would not be answered, because even the kind of people who ask those questions are probably capable of learning and realizing that asking a crap question that gets no answers is a waste of their own time. I reject your premise that answers have nothing to do with any of that, and you'll have to back it up with something better than "Shog and Brad said so".

Comment: @l4mpi We don't need to contradict your claim. It's your claim. Nobody says answers have nothing to do with it. We're saying you can control this without punishing people who happen to make the wrong judgement but posting a well meaning answer. It's ***that*** simple.

Comment: "We're saying you can control this without punishing people who happen to make the wrong judgement but posting a well meaning answer" - I don't care about _punishing_ people but about discouraging them from answering crap - although I would not have any problem with people losing rep for this (which is hardly a punishment, it's just a few fake internet points). But how would you "control" the user creating new accounts once they're questionbanned, without stopping them from getting answers? And "they'll be deleted eventually" is not helpful, that's just treating the symptoms.

Comment: @l4mpi - The system stopped that person from asking because it addressed the *asker*. You are basically proposing ways to prevent answerers from posting answers. Since this feature does not exist, you seem to personally feel the need to use downvotes in lieu of that functionality. If that were the way the system was designed to work, then there would be paths to close answers. But it is not the way it is designed because *answers are supposed to be encouraged*. In fact, encouraging good content is just as important as discouraging bad content.

Comment: @TravisJ the system evidently did _not_ stop them from asking, it just forced them to create a new account. Also, I don't personally downvote _good_ answers to bad questions, but can sympathize with those who do. You keep repeating "encouraging good content is just as important as discouraging bad content" which is exactly my point - answering a bad question can create good content (although I'd challenge that in case of the many entry level programming assignments getting solved on SO every day), but it also encourages or at least doesn't discourage the asker to create more bad content.

Comment: Discouraging the asker should be facilitated through downvotes,flags, closures, deletions, comments explaining how to create sscce's, and through question rate limiting or bans. There are many metrics in place to deal with askers, and there are even new features that keep coming which introduce barriers to low quality askers. Answering a bad question does not discourage a poor question, but that doesn't mean the answerer should be punished for trying to at least give some semblance of good faith to the asker. Especially considering the system is *already* dealing with the asker with its tools.

Comment: @TravisJ yeah, that's where our views completely differ - IMO the system cannot nearly do enough to deal with such cases. Some of the proposed measures are definite improvements, like throttling users sooner who continually ask bad questions. But none of these even try to address the reason _why_ people continually do so, which is because they're getting answers. I also don't get how losing rep would be punishment, we've already established on meta _downvotes are not punishment_ but an indication that a post is not useful.

Comment: @l4mpi - "useful" is not meant to be interpreted as "to the entire exchange", it is scoped to the current post. Downvoting proper answers because you are trying to personally implement a "don't answer this" policy is aimed at the user's *behavior* not their post and as a result your downvote is aimed at the user and not the post.

Comment: @TravisJ that might be your personal definition of "useful" but it has repeatedly been established that the community expects posts to be _useful to a larger audience_ and not just OP (remember "too localized" and consorts?). That of course holds true for the answer as well as the question - if the question cannot be made useful to anybody else, how would the answer be of any use? Which of course extends to votes as well, an answer that is useful only to OP can very well fit the SO definition of "not useful":

Comment: @l4mpi - I believe that is misconstruing too many paradigms. The community prefers questions to be useful to a larger audience, but does not immediately throw out questions which are not (remember when "too localized" was removed?). This of course does *not* hold true for answers as well as questions. And **in no way** extends to voting. Driving away answers will only serve to drive away experts.

Comment: @TravisJ "Driving away answers will only serve to drive away experts" - you keep repeating that without backing it up by facts, how can you be so sure about it? And note I am specifically talking about answers to bad questions; let's restrict it to deleted questions with negative score for the sake of the discussion. How can you be sure that doing anything to discourage answering such a question will be detrimental to the site? Nobody even tried it yet, and I'm not at all convinced this is true unless I see actual proof.

Comment: @l4mpi You can't post an answer to a deleted question, so I don't see how that fits in. Perhaps we should all be more clairvoyant. There is already a mechanism for stopping answers, and that is question closure. As for trying to prevent answers to open questions, the proof you would see would be the mass abandonment by experts and that would be tragic. Plenty of internet communities have come and gone as a result of rancor directed at users who are having positive interactions. If someone is using the site in a positive manner, then their interaction should not be discouraged.

Comment: @TravisJ I was talking about answering a qestion that is then closed and deleted, of course. As evident by many answered closed questions, closure is often too late to stop people from answering. As to your speculation about "mass abandonment", you've still not stated any facts, just your opinion what would happen. And btw, plenty of internet communities have gone down the drain due to getting too large and failing to keep up the quality, which is at least as likely to drive experts away. And I still reject your premise that answering crao is "using the site in a positive manner".

Comment: @l4mpi - Look at the post linked in this question. Who is being driven away as the result of negativity towards the answerer? The asker? Or the 342k rep user who is a highly valued community member?

Comment: @TravisJ probably not the answerer; why would a >300k rep member leave the site if some kind of punishmend for answering bad questions would be introduced (probably rep based which they wouldn't even feel anyways)? Anyways, that's still just baseless speculation and not facts...

Comment: Re: your late edit "premise that answering". Helping people learn is using the site in a positive manner. If the question is torn down then that is an indication to the asker they need to increase the quality of the questions they ask. It should in no way reflect the quality of the answers an answerer gives. If a question is low quality, that really has nothing to do with the answer being of high quality.

Comment: @l4mpi - It is not baseless though, that is the way the system is designed, to allow answers to open questions. As written, the system works just fine, and many experts are constantly posting answers. In order to make a change to that, *you* need to provide convincing evidence to support a change. All I need for evidence is status quo (go look for yourself at the millions of users, hundreds of thousands of answers, and an ever growing community). Simply taking it upon yourself to go downvote good answers through a narrow interpretation is not helping because it is fighting the system's design.

Comment: @TravisJ I already said I don't personally downvote if the answer is good; I just think the system could be _improved_ by also discouraging answers. And helping an individual person is still not the goal of SE. Also no, the _quantity_ of users is not evidence for the _quality_ of their contributions. Yahoo Answers and Quora "work" as well if measured like that. And if a question is low quality _and gets deleted_, that means the answer _cannot be useful to anybody_ because nobody can find it, which means it doesn't matter if it was awesome or bad.

Comment: @l4mpi - So, just to be clear, you do not think good answers should be downvoted solely based on the question's quality?

Comment: @TravisJ I do not personally do that; I do however understand the motives of the users who do, as many people feel that various measures taken by SE have made it harder to deal with crap and thus feel the need to personally deal with both sides of bad questions, asker and answerer. I do however usually check answers to questions I closevote more thoroughly, as they are often low quality as well - e.g. if I CV a question as unclear because OP leaves out critical points, and an answer comes along that makes unfounded assumptions, I will downvote and comment to not answer speculatively.

Comment: @l4mpi - Well if you have a feature in mind which could help that set of users deal with revoking the ability to answer bad questions faster then perhaps you should post it. In the end though, I believe any such feature would still focus on the question and asker, and not the answerer.

Comment: "[Fear doesn't wait for indications of a problem; it jumps at shadows, lashes out at memories.](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6698/im-challenging-us-to-make-the-christmas-2014-season-be-known-as-killing-them-w/6713#6713)"

Comment: @Shog9 not so much fear as actually having my favourite tags overrun with crap. Have you visited [python] lately? Every time I refresh the main page I see multiple dv- and closeworthy questions. It's more frustration than anything else at this point. I just refreshed - four downvotes, three closevotes. At least none were answered yet; still demotivates me from doing anything else on SO. And all responses from staff like you are either denial or downplay, but there's been nothing that had a positive effect on my experience of the site (there's enough changes I'd describe as negative though).

Comment: @l4mpi "I see multiple dv- and closeworthy questions". That's not the problem at hand. You can raise your concerns in your own discussion on Meta. You're simply barking up the wrong tree here. I'd be interested to know how you think the influx should be reduced.

Comment: @sehe well, we already found out that our experience of the site differs. But for me, it _is_ the problem at hand. I'd love questions that "tickle my curiosity", but these are rare and hard to find in the python tag - instead SO shoves tons of crap in my face. And I already said one thing I'd do, which is disincentivizing _answers_ to bad questions; I don't have a specific feature in mind but e.g. a warning if a question you answered is closed and deleted, and a rep penalty if that's happening too often. I don't think that has any chance of being implemented though.

Comment: That warning could be a helpful feature - in case the answerer wasn't aware. Any kind of penalty is just stupid. The day that happens to me, SO lost me. When I spend time looking at a question (if only to provide feedback on its quality), I sometimes stumble upon the real question or just generally good things to note. I feel it's wasteful not to comment that. If it is significant I leave an answer. Everyone is free to not upvote that if they want to teach the OP to ask better questions. But downvoting is downright aggravating. (Unless the answer is bad).

Comment: Also: Ahahaha. You think I don't see tons of crap? Maybe I just filter better. I'm really really selective of what I view on SO. I choose not to focus on the drivel, so I don't go into a panicky "ermagahd must close _baaad_ questions" mode. That's an attitude. Trying to janitor everything to clinically clean standards (a) doesn't scale (you know: it's stressful!) and (b) kills the life. Look at nature: You can leave the dirt to rot. (It might even be beneficial in unexpected ways). No need to scare vultures away "because you don't want to encourage rotting corpses".

Comment: Note we share a similar motivation: we don't want to waste our time. Main difference I see is: _you_ focus on the negatives ("I don't want to deal with the crap, it's demotivating me"). I focus on what I can contribute. I follow the tags I want to hone my skills in. I'll spend effort reading the questions. If SO teaches me to let my efforts go to waste (because it's not politically correct to share it), that will be my demotivator. So the real question to answer is: why are you spending time on SO? What is your personal goal? What's in it for you? Find your motivation and you can deal with it.

Comment: Just found https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/541 which is heavily related and an interesting read. I've also found a very important difference between our use of SO: I downvote about 14 times as often as you do (~7.4k in 3.2 years vs 1k in 5.8 years). I think it's pretty much a given that you filter better; but I still believe it's important to vote down all of this crap - without these votes you would probably having a harder time filtering.

Answer (score 6):

The question is drowning in fluff (~80%), being essentially:

> ## Have problem, need help coding.
>
> I am stumped on starting my homework, please help:
>
> > Write a program that prompts the user to enter the weight of a person in kilograms and outputs the equivalent weight in pounds. Output both the weights rounded to two decimal places.

As should be immediately obvious from the copy-edited question, that's simply "too broad", far too localized and should be closed, downvoted and deleted.
Anything making deletion less likely is just *not helpful*.

Now, to that specific answer: SO is not for personal tutoring, that's specifically outside its scope.

Comment: "Anything making deletion less likely is just not helpful" - this, a thousand times. Sadly I can only upvote it once.

Answer (score 5):

> Did I act right here?

No. You downvoted a useful post and started having a mind-altering experience in the comments.

The question was also not a "help vampire" question.

However, I tend to agree that I wish blatantly off-topic questions would not be answered, because it does send the wrong signal to the author. Especially when the question is subsequently and inevitably going to be deleted.

And this *was* one, since this is not a helpdesk or a chatroom where you can get "hints", "tips" or "guidance" — honestly, when will some people accept this? Rightfold said it best:

> *[..]* Stack Overflow isn't a help website but a knowledge base in Q&A format. If you don't tell them they'll assume it's a help website because that's what they want.

Posting an answer regardless of the question's validity, just because "I want to *help* the OP" is not necessarily the best thing to do. Helping people is great, but this notion that it must come above any other concern is ludicrous, especially when "helping" is so difficult to quantify; in software development, certainly, the value of ones knowledge and experience is certainly subjective. That way, Experts Exchange lies.

But I still think that erring on the side of *not* blindly downvoting everything and trying to "eliminate" the author as if SO were some kind of virtual Hunger Games arena is probably in the best interest of everyone involved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems in the comments that some users are implying the question asker is a help vampire. Let's go through the [help vampire checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem):

> - Do they ask the same, tired questions others ask (at a rate of once or more per minute)?

This is from what I can tell the user's first and only question, there's no pattern of repeated behavior here.

> - Do they clearly lack the ability or inclination to ask the almighty Google?

The question is so localized that google is unlikely to be helpful.

> - Do they refuse to take the time to ask coherent, specific questions?

The question seems pretty coherent and specific to me.

> - Do they think helping them must be the high point of your day?

AFAICT the user hasn't exhibited this, but the screenshots are small and I'm not 10k.

> - Do they get offensive, as if you needed to prove them why they should use Ruby on Rails?

Same as above.

> - Are they obviously just waiting for some poor, well-intentioned person to do all their thinking for them?

This is the case of many students. A student is not necessarily a help vampire and a help vampire is not necessarily a student.

> - Can you tell they really aren't interested in having their question answered, so much as getting someone else to do their work?

This does seem to be the case here, but I think a key idea is that we simply *don't* know. We don't know what the user has tried, what they have gone through or what they're struggling with, whether they have a crappy teacher or in some programming class whose curriculum is recycled from the '90s. What we're confident of is that SO has given us the tools to downvote, delete, close and move on. I sometimes think that users can often overreact to a low quality question with such inexplicable hostility that it drives away people.

If someone wants to take time out of their day to help somebody or post an answer to a low quality question, great, you can downvote it. But beyond that, I wouldn't make a judgment call. After all, there are hundreds of teachers and tutors who deal with help vampires *daily* and you wouldn't discount their hard work, would you?

Comment: _"that some users are implying the question asker is a help vampire"_ Well they're look like a new help vampire coming up. Arguable if we should allow them getting to evolve from their coffins a bit. I prefer to stick the wooden pole to their heart, before they even have a chance to blink!

Comment: I didn't research this particular question-asker, but my comments about *actual* help vampires still stands.

Comment: @J.Steen The rhetoric about help vampires pops up every now and then but it serves no purpose other than to add fuel to the flame, *unless* it applies to the situation at hand. After all, the purpose of meta is to address actual problems.

Comment: @emyabel _"Asking for guidance ..."_ smells from that vamp grave/coffin so much :-P. We should consult Van Helsing, but I'm pretty sure he wouldn't hesitate to react immeadeatly!

Comment: @remyabel My rhetoric was left, in this case, as comments just for the reason that it might not apply to the exact situation at hand. The purpose of meta, for me, is to discuss issues both specific and general, where specific cases spark general debate. But. I'll bow out, since this obviously isn't about actual help vampirism (**yet**) - just a new user who hasn't read the help pages.

Comment: I also use far too many commas.

Comment: @remyabel Why should we wait for the 2nd bite, before eliminating the vampire? See [member for today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4573901/jason-lutes), it just goes [from dusk till dawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dusk_till_Dawn)

Comment: The fact that the user may not yet fit your definition of "help vampire" doesn't result in any coherent argument here. The first reason you cite is that it's the users first question - which makes it even more important to _not_ answer it and to make it clear that these kinds of questions should not be asked on SO. Furthermore, you say "the question seems pretty coherent and specific to me" - what? It's not even a question, it's a copypaste of their assignment. A question would be something like "please explain this specific part" or "I tried this and it fails, why"; not "do my assignment".

Comment: @l4mpi Your examples of specific/coherent questions are even worse. That's the equivalent of "it doesn't work".

Comment: Note I have only 600 characters to work with, I can hardly write an essay. These were meant as examples for the _minimal_ requirement for a question, namely identifying a specific, narrow, answerable part, or describing a specific attempt (and of course giving at least an error message and a stacktrace in case of an error, or the wrong and expected output in case of a wrong result). And I don't see how any of that is worse than "I have no idea what I'm doing but here's my assignment".

Answer (score -21):

I think that the "quality of the site" smells of elitism.

Unless the same user asks these inane questions over and over again *and* you happen to stumble upon them as well, I would not accuse them of being a help vampire.

Either answer such question smartly, not will full code but in school book style, or just leave it alone and let others decide if they want to help him or not.

<sub>(Side note: But then again, I disagree even with closing of questions regarding libraries recommendations.)</sub>

Comment: Again: _"Asking for guidance ..."_ smells from that vamp grave/coffin so much :-P. We should consult Van Helsing, but I'm pretty sure he wouldn't hesitate to react immeadeatly, take the wooden pole and stab it right through their heart!

Comment: Why should we wait for the 2nd bite, before eliminating the vampire?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: IMO, you are not waiting even for the first. You primitively stake them with a sharp aspen stick.

Comment: @wilx - too difficult without training.  Same with beheading - use fire.