# Is using Stack Overflow for gimme codez questions encouraged?

Tags: discussion, questions

There seems to be now be an implicit license for "gimme codez" questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083134 and associated reputation gains for cheap answers to such questions. Is this what Stack Overflow wishes to be known for? I didn't bother to search for answers on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) so please just gimme me an answer.

---

Okay, I did search for policy on such matters, but I can't seem to find anything more recent than [Encouraging users to try something before asking "Write me code that..." questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135049/encouraging-users-to-try-something-before-asking-write-me-code-that-questio/135051#135051) which itself is vastly more permissive than the older [What site to use if you have a "gimme teh codez" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question)

Does anyone have pointers to policy that I missed? If my anecdotal view of the current norms is correct, then the purpose of this site has changed, and I can ignore it in good conscience.

Comment: My take on it is while the norms of the core group of Stack Overflow *hasn't* changed, the core group is lacking in tools or sufficient eyeballs to be able to fight against the tide of the questions of people asking, and the new users who are not as familiar with the norms to answer.  Related [A Group is its own worst enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html) (the bit about Communitree may be applicable).

Comment: You may want to look at this [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)

Comment: The SE staff doesn't seem to care (after all, as long as ad revenue is coming, why should they?) as they removed the close reasons applicable for these questions. I used to flag the questions for other reasons (unclear what you're asking, too broad or cannot be reproduced/typo error) but I've given up since then.

Comment: @AndréDaniel you are a very few rep points away from 3k... which should drastically help in your ability to moderate the site with close votes.

Comment: @MichaelT yeah I know but even then, there is no right close reason for these questions, so I'll have to slightly bend the rules by voting to close with a less than optimal close reason.

Comment: @AndréDaniel off topic - fix my code, too broad, and unclear are all possibly applicable reasons for "give me the code" type questions. Fix my code asks for some code first to fix along with a clear problem statement.  Too broad is applicable under the "too many possible answers" (often the case with give me the code questions), and unclear as in the "please specify exactly what you are asking for (that is within the scope of the site)".

Comment: Shouldn't users with very high reputation help out by NOT answering questions like that?

Comment: The linked question only netted the answerer a gain of 15 rep points for the accepted answer and zero upvotes, so it's not exactly cheap and easy rep. I think that by and large the incentives (in terms of rep) are already roughly correct: gimme the codez questions are not well rewarded compared to more general answers that help lots of people and therefore get lots of upvotes. Who cares if the answerer gets a measly 15 rep? He already has 60k+ so it's reasonable to assume he just answered to help somebody, not for "rep whoring" since 15 points is just a drop in the bucket.

Comment: @MyCarta Unfortunately, some of those users are just keen on getting a bigger number, however that might happen. Or, to be kinder, some just love helping anyone and everyone, with any kind of question.

Comment: _"There seems to be now be an implicit license for "gimme codez" questions like split first coulmn of each lines respect to the remainig columns"_ Ehm, since when? This is DIScouraged!

Comment: Until people stop getting positive rep scores for an accepted answer on a poor question, it's 'encouraged'. There's a feedback loop of help vampires and rep whores. Help vampires come back because they get answers. Repwhores keep answering because they keep gaining rep. If you broke this cycle, you'd get a lot less poor quality questions, because there wouldn't be a 'fastest gun in west' rush to the shootout. It takes 7 downvotes to cancel out an 'accepted answer'. But IMO you shouldn't be cancelling anything, but rather inhibiting the initial reward.

Comment: As noted in a comment on [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083134/split-first-column-of-each-lines-respect-to-the-remaining-columns) the automatic question ban will take care of a lot of this if bad questions are downvoted. A possible way to address the "rep-whoring" issue would be to remove rep earned for answers on closed questions.

Comment: @BobJarvis reputation is unawarded when a question is deleted and the post doesn't meet sufficient grandfathering requirements. Not that that should be much of an issue.  The key point is that poor quality questions that do not provide value to the site need to be deleted - then everything else follows from that action. Finding [poor quality questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a..-3%20closed%3ano) is the first step in closing them. Then [going and deleting them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a..-3%20closed%3ayes).

Comment: Item 3 in [this help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is as close as I could find to an official statement about such questions. I usually vote to close on that basis. I find it somewhat discouraging how many "do my homework" seekers are out there. And then there are cases where they do a little bit of work, you help them 95% of the rest of the way, and then they have the nerve to come back with things like, *Thanks! That's great! But I also need to print the letter "a" when it's done, can you fix it?*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree it should be, but if you look at the CSS tags, there's almost *no* systemic discouragement going on, compared to the massive volume of new questions being asked. They took away the relevant CV reasons, so now it's *hard* to close that kind of crap. Which means almost no one does it.

Comment: @TylerH There's no disputing a great many people flout generally-accepted guidelines on posting behaviour. That doesn't mean the community encourages doing so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A great many people *don't know* the generally-accepted guidelines on posting behavior. The problem is that we don't require users to learn the rules before posting a question. We only enforce them ex post facto.

Comment: @TylerH: Um how do you "require users to learn the rules before posting a question"? This is fundamentally infeasible. Stack Overflow throws the rules in the faces of new users, taking a _great_ effort to encourage users to learn. But, ultimately, they just want immediate help and don't give a crap about reading the rules, nor are they even really aware that they _should_ give a crap about reading the rules. There is _nothing_ you can do about that, other than forcing them into a multiple-choice test about the rules, which they would pass then ignore the rules.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not suggesting we require them to learn the rules before posting a question (though it's definitely *not* infeasible, fundamentally or otherwise; we require membership and contribution for nearly all functions and abilities of Stack Overflow), merely positing it as the *reason* why we have lots of bad (in our view) questions.

Comment: It _is_ infeasible and that topic has been beaten to death many, many times over the years.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nah, just require rep to ask a question. That's a pretty feasible change to the code base.

Comment: @TylerH: [Oh, really?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164377/155739)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If that's what you mean (and I don't dispute the contents of that link), then "feasible" wasn't the word you were looking for.

Comment: @TylerH: I didn't say it's infeasible to code it up. I said it's infeasible to require users to learn the rules before posting a question. One may accrue 500 rep without learning any rules. Hell, there are 50k users running around doing silly things. _It's infeasible to derive an effective solution from such a piece of code._

Comment: @Sobrique would be interesting to see [Voting stats for “desperate accept” answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601), wouldn't it

Comment: A couple of my suggestions for: [newer users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) and [low quality question checks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw with the Stack Overflow model, in that the 'benefit' for helping out is reputation. People will chase reputation, because pretty fundamentally - that's the point of it being there. But as reputation drives behaviour, it doesn't *necessarily* drive the right behaviour.

closing a bad question doesn't yield rep. Answering it (then voting to close) probably will.

Indeed, given my (albeit limited) scope - high scoring answers tend to be on simpler questions because:

- More people look, because they think they can answer
- More people can understand the answer is 'good' so are more likely to upvote.

Reputation doesn't scale for 'good' or 'bad' questions. There's no (direct) penalty for answers to 'gimme codez' questions. Worst case - you spend a few minutes knocking something together, and you lose the (small amount) of rep if and when it ever gets deleted.

I think the answer really has to be a bit of a rethink to the reward model. Perhaps something as simple as reward scaling, that requires a question to have a higher-than-zero ( >1 maybe?) score in order to be eligible for upvote bonuses?

And for a really *good* question - one that's not had many answers - perhaps a bonus to encourage people to take the time. (Above and beyond that offered by 'bounties').

Comment: this could be less of an issue if SE team was less reluctant to implement [their own ideas on more efficient auto-delete](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601) "...we dispense with the logic that preserves answers with 1 vote or an accept mark that will stay deletion at 9 days. Downvoted duplicates are also added to the mix..." - this way would at least remove rep-whoring motivation to answer questions that are quickly voted down and closed

Comment: True. Deferring rep awards until we know it's _not_ going to be autodeleted might also do the trick - there's no "quick win, punishment later" cycle.

Comment: There was a proposal about removing rep on closed questions, that might fix it - but don't know how the idea is getting on. I think it would be worth a go, though existing rep would have to be frozen.

Comment: I like the idea, but I think it might be better if e.g. rep rewards were simply 'held' for an initial interval (say, a day or two) so the question has a chance to be downvoted or closed... and if it is, no rep is awarded in the first place.

Comment: Best answer. The essence of what made Stack Overflow succeed is that it was a game with better incentives that what we had previously (primarily forums). Relying on human moderation or "good nature" to fix problems means that Stack Overflow has forgotten the most important reason for its success.

Comment: I've never understood people who both answer and VTC the same question.  Either the question deserves to be answered, or it doesn't.  Let's not be two-faced, or arrogant enough to believe "well, my answer deserves to be here, but nobody else's does".

Comment: It's pretty simple - it's bare faced rep whoring. The system rewards you for doing it, therefore people do. Which is kind of my point - we have rep as an incentive mechanism. We should not be surprised when people do things to optimise their rep gains. And as for answering and VTC - a question can be answerable but still offtopic. A more generous soul might offer 'the answer is this, but by the way this is offtopic.'

Answer (score 36):

Is it *encouraged*? Absolutely not. Does it happen? Of course, we can't always moderate fast enough.

Do note that the expected answer to *many* Stack Overflow questions is code that performs some function (along with an explanation of course), we just want to take care that the *question* is of high quality and not just "Give me code that does X".

Comment: The worse thing is that we are actually _discouraged_ to downvote/flag these answers, that correctly fulfill the OP's demands. We should have a kind of _"rep whoring"_ close reason IMHO. The only hope is that such VLQ/LQ questions are being deleted in whole quickly (and thus the _rep whores_ loose the incentive).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suspect that promptly closing, down voting, and if necessary deleting the fresh questions can help send a signal as to their applicability on the site. [is:question closed:yes score:..-3 answers:1](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20closed%3ayes%20score%3a..-3%20answers%3a1) finds low scoring questions that have answers that are eligible for 20k delete votes (and if they don't get deleted serve a good chance of being examples for future poor quality questions and answers).

Comment: @MichaelT Oh, what a very nice quick search :), THX! It even [works with my favorite tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes+score%3A..-3+answers%3A1).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As long as you are prepared to gift one downvote, -2 is actually a reasonable limit. Too often, there's no votes left though, already used up moderating.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - This [has been discussed in many places](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286236/19679), but downvoting and otherwise harassing experts who leave good answers to bad questions only drives away those experts, not the ones asking the bad questions. The thing is, they mostly don't know or care that they are asking bad questions and will do whatever they can to post them. It pretty much doesn't matter if bad questions get answers or not, they're going to keep coming as long as Stack Overflow sits at the top of Google searches.

Comment: @BradLarson there is a difference between down voting experts (though this brings up the question of "can there be a good answer to a bad question" which leads to other discussions) and deleting questions that should be deleted from the site but are being kept here because they have an answer that is either upvoted or accepted. There is a reason that people have delete votes - to help remove the noise from the pool of questions so that the good questions are more visible. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19933020/) a good question? should it be deleted? or preserved because a 20k answered?

Comment: I will mention that I am in agreement with the opinion on "good answers to bad questions" given [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237471/). The question is how much time does a person have to invest in moderating Stack Overflow. Votes are the lowest time commitment approaches. Editing to fix the question is one of the highest. It is unfortunate that the experts who answered the question didn't put that time investiment in the question in the first place - to either fix the question or find a dup for it. Please do not stigmatize those who are trying to set a minimum standard for questions.

Comment: @BradLarson Answering low quality questions *absolutely* encourages people to post more low quality questions.  Not answering any low quality questions wouldn't eliminate *all* low quality questions everywhere, forever, but it means that people will give up on posting low quality questions after asking one or two instead of us having users that have asked hundreds of low quality questions because they keep getting mediocre answers.  Additionally a correct answer to a terrible question is highly unlike to be a *useful* answer, even if it's correct, due to all of the problems with the quesiton.

Comment: Remember its often faster for [an expert to toss out a quick answer to a poor question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129939/) than it is to find people who are willing to moderate the site. And that such is "don't down vote it because it chases away experts" doesn't mean that they can't write crap answers too that *should* be down voted and deleted. It took an [hour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29014859/)  to get close votes, yet a 20k was able to get an answer in... but that shouldn't prevent it from having delete votes cast - because its not a good question.

Comment: Moderation (closing a dupe, etc.) takes some time/effort, and doesn't get rewarded with rep. Offering a quick answer does. (Downvoting a quick answer to a lazy question actively _costs_ rep). Given the whole point of reputation is gamification and a motivation mechanism, we're not rewarding the right behaviours.

Comment: @BradLarson: by the time they become "experts" in the [so] sense, they should have been taught not to answer bad questions. If they don't, then I'm willing to see them driven away.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - That's an extremely hostile attitude, and I certainly do not share it. We're talking about volunteers who just want to help people. The whole site is built around encouraging that. Driving away helpful, friendly experts will only hurt the site and further reinforce the impression that this place is full of intolerant elites. It will do absolutely nothing to stem the tide of low-quality content. Poor questions will keep coming in as long as this site sits atop Google searches, and whether or not they get answers will make no difference.

Comment: @BradLarson "whether or not they get answers will make no difference" - that might be true for new users who flood the site, but after asking two or three questions without getting an answer, even the most dense people would surely find something better to do with their time. Answering bad questions is a direct incentive to _not_ improve question quality.

Comment: @l4mpi - After deleting the seventh question-banned account of a particular user, I looked back at the 20+ questions they dumped on the site. Only one had received an answer of any kind, yet they kept coming. I see this pattern repeated many times over. It's these kinds of users that are our worst problem right now, and they will keep trying to get this site to do their work for them even if we prevent them from getting answers.

Comment: @BradLarson ok, seems like some people are far more dense than I can possibly imagine; I would still hope that those are a minority. Well, at least your comment definitely confirms my long-held assumption that the supposed block/throttling of people who deleted and re-created an account is either an outright lie or completely useless...

Comment: @l4mpi - It's not that the system doesn't exist, or that it's a lie that recreating your account works against you, it's that it isn't as effective as it should be. There's a lot more that can be done here, and things are being rolled out in stages. Moderators are able to manually target and block repeat offenders that we see, but I think the worry is that if we do this the wrong way tons of innocent people could be blocked from using the site. Significant improvements in the way this system works could have a dramatic effect on the overall quality of content coming in, from what I see.

Comment: @BradLarson "That's an extremely hostile attitude..." In the years I've been answering questions here, I've seen the systematic removal of tags and close reasons that guide the OP into what they might have gotten wrong. Back in the USENET days, "RTFM" was a valid answer that was accepted by the community; might someone feel downhearted by that? Sure. Between RTFM and RTFAQ, as cruel as they may appear, it did convey "we'd love to help you, but you have to have put a modicum of effort in first". I think that completely fair but certainly not nice.

Answer (score 32):

**Whooooooooooo cares?**

This behavior - "code-begging" - used to really annoy me on forums and mailing lists, because you'd put the time into answering one of these and... Your work would sink beneath the waves forever. You were, by and large, writing for the benefit of **one person** - so wanting to make sure that they *deserved* the effort is pretty fair. Not that you really *could* - generally, the best you could hope for is someone who'd at least respond and let you know that your answer worked before you and everyone else forgot about it forever.

Yeah, forums were pretty broken for this sorta thing. But that's why Stack Overflow was created in the first place...

See, **you are not at the mercy of the asker here.** Even if they take your answer and disappear forever, your answer sticks around to help the *next* person with the same problem. The first person to ask for code to do *X* could be a lazy, no-good resume-padding ingrate, *and it still doesn't matter* - your answer is still there for everyone else who might need to do *X*, most of whom will *also* be lazy ingrates *because they come from The Internet and that's what Internet People are like* but... You'll get a few who aren't, a few for whom your answer will make a difference, a few who'll *give back* when the tables are turned and they find themselves possessing unique knowledge of how to do *Y*...

...and **that's how Stack Overflow works.**

When I first learned to program, I saved for probably a month to buy a crappy copy of Turbo C. I read the worthless book that came with it, the (actually quite good) online documentation, and in another month I'd managed to become... a really lousy C programmer. Then I found my way onto the 'Net, and all the open source I could eat. And for the next few years, I downloaded and read and learned... Eventually, I started answering others' programming questions - not because they deserved it, but because **I didn't deserve** any of the education I got, and yet it was freely-given anyway.

A good many of these questions - like your example - have other problems: they're unclear, they're impossibly broad, they're duplicates... But in the absence of all of that, if the worst you can say about a given question is, "I don't think the asker deserves code" then... Stop caring about the asker. They may be a spoiled kid like I used to be, but that doesn't mean *only* such characters will benefit from your work - *if* you desire to write, then write, write for the ages and write for the masses, and sooner or later someone will appreciate the lessons you've taught.

Comment: Writing for the masses is great. Writing to very specific requirements of the asker's daily task, not so much. But since close reasons do not allow for a distinction between what's widely applicable and what's *too localized*, that distinction gets lost.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job then, @Woodface. If only there was some sort of system that quietly removed questions *no one cares about*...

Comment: If only that system removed questions *and* answers no one cares about, without having them to go through closure...

Comment: The [30 and 365 day criteria for autodeletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/1438) do not require the question to be closed. It turns out the there are currently _twice_ as many deleted questions as closed questions and the vast majority of deletions are automated.

Comment: @JonEricson and a single answer will prevent those scripts from activating.  Two comments asking for clarification will prevent the 365 day one. And I can point out that there quite a bit of crap out there at +1/-0 from a generous first post reviewer.

Comment: Who cares? I think **[Mark Trapp explained this over 4 years ago, didn't he?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)** "...I see a **list of questions**. If most of those are terrible questions with little to no indication that I’d be wasting my time by reading them, the value proposition of visiting and participating is diminished: I have better things to do..."

Comment: ...in that sense, I think we're indeed at mercy... not of the (single) asker but of the **(multiple) askers**. Poisoning site/tag pages with multiple garbage questions is a proven way to frustrate core users ever [since ancient times of Communitree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged#comment165986_288133 "used as example in 'A Group is its own worst enemy'")

Comment: And yet, as I have had to explain to multiple users, most programmers will not be searching for "How to draw an asterisk triangle in C#", they would instead be searching for information about loops. Questions that ask for code are *fine* but they need to be more than "give me the code that fits these requirements" to be useful "for the ages".

Comment: Strawman, @gnat. You wanna look at a poorly-asked question and say, "the real problem here is that he's asking for something" then... Well, you're kinda blind. By all means, get rid of crap - downvote it, flag it, close it, delete it... But don't try to find some magical metric divorced from the question's scope and clarity, because that inevitably damns *everything.*

Comment: I have no problem looking at a _single_ poorly asked question. Guess what, I have no problem looking at _many_ such questions... in the respective review queue. The elephant in the room is, there is a dangerous flood of such questions polluting site/tags pages, as suggested by 180+ upvotes at [Allow users to optionally filter out low-quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253351/839601) and  300+ at [The Stack Overflow homepage is over-emphasizing bad questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/839601)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Perhaps not programmers, but other clueless students will... and traffic is traffic.

Comment: @Woodface  Java vs C# questions drive traffic as well, but we don't encourage/allow *those*... Essentially, the fact that it drives traffic is not sufficient for it to be deemed acceptable.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation) then, @gnat. The homepage is already filtering a bunch of these questions, but there are a lot of other lists that need some filtering...

Comment: sort of. Though I am rather looking into [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged/288256#comment166642_288256): "low quality questions still show up for most of our users..."

Comment: This is the best answer I have even seen on Meta.  The amount of whining and hand-wringing that goes on here is unbelievable.

Answer (score 25):

You're running into the issue that SE is a site that has very few rules.  It has lots of guidelines.

You'll constantly see people violating site guidelines, for any number of reasons.  Whether it's a good thing is of course something to be evaluated on a case by case basis.

Nobody can tell you whether some particular action is going to be universally correct or incorrect.  People can give you their opinion on whether a particular action is beneficial or harmful in a particular instance.  The site guidelines are effectively an "average" of the opinions of many users across many similar situations.

Comment: IMHO, this is the worst part of SE, too much guidelines used rigorously as if they were rules. Since average won't fit in many cases, after the "rule" is misapplied you get the "I'm only human" excuse and have to live with it. This is a good source of frustation, for both sides.

Answer (score 11):

By "gimme codez", do you mean like this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094976/how-to-subtract-array-values-from-array-values-in-php

...or like this?

[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

I think it's important to note that there's a difference between "write some code for me" and "what code can I use to do this one specific thing?" As long as the questions are appropriately scoped (e.g. such that it's likely other people will encounter the same problem in the future), I don't see a problem.

I'm going to agree with [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288134/1157054) here in saying that this is something that should "be evaluated on a case by case basis." Vote up the useful questions, vote down the not-so-useful questions, and vote to close the questions that are too broad or unclear.

Comment: Actually the second case (although voted up way more than it merits) at least shows an example attempt and asks for further help. I consider that legit. I don't have a handy example link, but more than once I've seen posts that literally have maybe 3 sentences that say something to the effect that, *I need a program a function in C that does xyz. Can someone please help me? It's due in an hour!*.

Comment: Another difference is that the first question is a low-quality, somewhat unclear/broad noob question that is neither going to attract high-quality answers nor be findable enough for anybody with a similar issue; while the other one is a useful reference with a googleable title and thus close to a million views. While I in principle agree with the case by case basis, it's clear which case is the vast majority of no-effort questions being currently asked.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should find some better examples. That first question has a number of problems with it other than just scope. My point though was that question scope can make a big difference in whether a question asking for code is useful or not. If a lot of other people are likely to have the same problem, even a not-so-amazing "What code can I use to do this?" question could potentially help hundreds or (in extreme cases) even hundreds of thousands of people.

Comment: I chose the question that heads this thread because the question is pure "gimme codez" and the one answer explains nothing at all. Without explanation, a chunk of code is like the proverbial "giving a man a fish". It is possible that the OP of that thread was able to generalize that answer into personal wisdom, but since he couldn't  cobble that half-line of code for himself, I doubt it.

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question in the title:

[image: -19]

Now the voting is extreme thanks to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), but clearly people don't like these questions. By why not?

### They violate a sense of professionalism.

I think we all have been in the situation where someone finds out that we work with computers and asks us to fix their laptop or whatever. If it's someone you care about, you'll probably do what you can to help. But it seems rude for someone you just met to ask you to do *pro bono* work. Same thing applies on Stack Overflow *except everyone is a stranger*. Programmers spend countless hours tinkering with code in order to be able to solve little problems like this. So it feels like the asker is cheating if they get a solution without struggle.

Thankfully, Stack Exchange offers a very simple solution: downvotes. No need to comment, [just downvote and move on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135051/1438). Downvoting does two things:

1. It signals to the asker that they did something wrong.
2. It [slows them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) from asking more questions.

The second point gets overlooked. The user who asked the question you pointed to won't be able to ask questions anytime soon because of the downvotes they've received. We've been working to make an even better system with the [Triage Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage). Many low quality questions don't get to the homepage until they are vetted. (Unfortunately, people looking to answer questions [aren't using the homepage](http://www.sklivvz.com/posts/stack-overflow-answer-sources-by-the-numbers) as much as we thought they did. So low quality questions still show up for most of our users. We probably need to fix that.)

### A caution against anecdotal evidence

We find reports like yours very useful because they help us improve Stack Overflow. But it's helpful to look at data too. I've [been fooled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210266/1438) by my subjective impressions too many times to not look at the data. Here's how many questions are asked, closed and deleted each week:

[image: Asked, closed, and deleted]

The rate of questions has leveled off, but we are still deleted more than 10,000 questions a week and closing about 5,000. Nearly all of the deletions are [automatically signaled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/1438) by the community downvoting questions. If a certain type of question is encouraged, it will be because those questions are upvoted by the community. I just don't see that happening right now for questions that are simply asking for code.

To heed my own advice, I should probably look at the data. Unfortunately, it's hard to detect these sorts of questions automatically. That's one of the reasons we have voting on questions.

Comment: _low quality questions still show up for most of our users_ -- ["out of sight, out of mind..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-3-algorithm-tweaks/274602#comment108869_274602)

Comment: I'm wondering whether the fact that the number of closed and deleted questions SEEMS like a larger percentage is because most of the really good questions are in niche tags, that few people ever look at, whereas most of the crap goes into the popular tags that everyone sees.  Or even due to the fact that the more people see a question, the more likely it is to get closed.  It would be interesting to see this same data weighted by the number of views that each question has had.

Comment: @DavidWallace stats would probably be for _number of views_ on asked / closed / deleted questions in order to account for that

Comment: Does anyone know why the dips in the graph?  do they coincide with Christmas Day by any change?  The only day that less coders go on stackoverflow?

Comment: @TobyAllen: Yes, the two week drop each year is around Christmas and New Years.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with a lot of what has been said already but I wanted to add that SO is a system and we participate in it by choice. One day might be a "I just feel like coding" day, another might be "I feel like educating this person on the guidelines" day. Just fill the role you feel like filling in the moment and let someone else do the other.

In saying that it is a system I would like to draw attention to the review queues. by participating in this way, I have learned more about what makes a good question and more about how to separate the good from the bad. and I'm still learning.

Answer (score -2):

I'm constantly amazed at the number of people who seem to consider that (their or other people's?) behaviour is driven by reputation brownie points. I would have hoped that as professionals we were above such things.

When I respond to a question I do it the same way as when someone stops me on the street and asks for directions. I'll give the best advice I can in the time available. I will only make a detour to take them to their destination if I think it will be an interesting diversion (for me): normally I'll just point them in the right direction and encourage them to find their own way. All the time, I'm thinking that my purpose is not just to help them solve their immediate problem, but to encourage them to improve their skills and become more able to help themselves (and others) in the future.

I don't approve of voting down the question. I do approve of answering it in a way that encourages people to do their own research either before or after asking it, and I'm disappointed when people respond with a yard of uncommented code that won't teach them anything.

Comment: And I never downvote anything without saying why.

Comment: I don't link comments and downvotes. If i have a suggestion for the user to  improve their question, i leave it as a comment. If not, i move on. If i think the question is unclear or could use more research, i downvote. Doesn't mean i need to comment, the downvote should take care of that. I do comment on the majority of questions that i downvote, but i don't comment just because i downvoted.

Comment: [vote split here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601) suggests that there are probably 41 meta visitors who could vote against indiscriminate-answering approach and 9 that would support it. "...Don't ever answer a [obviously off-topic] question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want."

Comment: "I do approve of answering it in a way that encourages people to do their own research either before or after asking it" I agree with this stance completely which is why I chose the particular thread to ask about; the answer gives no explanation and teaches nothing. The OP asked "gimme code" for the and was merely given code.