# Should I flag a question that I think should be reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, help-center, reopen-closed

I am trying to get a good question reopened, so I searched for how I should do that and found the [*What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) page. The page recommends flagging the question:

> Additionally, you can:
>
> ...
>
> 3. Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, explain why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators
>      do reconsider their decisions.

So I flagged the question and explained in detail why it should be reopened. My flag was declined with the following message: "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention."

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the *Reopen Questions* page, but it seems like it is contradicting the action taken by this moderator. I'm not sure if the page needs to be updated or I somehow should have known not to flag a question to get it reopened. It's also worth noting that under 3k users are encouraged to flag questions that need to be closed, so it seems quite natural to flag questions that need to be reopened.

Comment: Only flag it none of the other options works, and you make a convincing case in your message. And even then, the [SOCVRV](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) would be faster than a mod-flag, and allows you to fix a fumbled attempt.

Comment: Where's the question link?  Who's afraid of the big, bad meta effect?

Comment: The ME can work both ways - it may help get the question reopened, (or bury it).

Comment: @MartinJames, I was under the impression that it was impolite to post a question for the meta effect. If you want to question, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974692/liferay-jsf-portlet-edit-mode-popup

It's short, but completely clear and not too difficult to answer with a few lines of code.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I have insufficient knowledge in that area to vote either way, sorry:(

Comment: Well, I have my doubts, by I plain don't know whether that question may be reopened, or it deserves a faster burial. It's quite likely the mod handling your flag is no more knowledgeable in that corner...

Comment: @MartinJames, yeah, I think that the close voters may also not be experts on this question. It is kinda a niche topic (Liferay Portlets + JSF).

Comment: *["To the close voters: please comment on how this is too broad."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974692/liferay-jsf-portlet-edit-mode-popup#comment57723478_34974692)*. That's not going to be a popular request (if any of them ever see it, which is unlikely).

Comment: But whether or not you agree with the specifics, I think it's still worthwhile to have a discussion here about whether under 3k users should flag to reopen and whether the *Reopen Questions* page text should be changed.

Comment: I'd guess that some of the close votes were cast because — as written — the question has a strong [gimme teh codez](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged) odor. If that's *not* the case, consider editing the question to make that clear. This will both improve the question and place it in the Reopen Review queue.