# Should this question be flagged or answered?

Tags: discussion

I had a discussion with [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751125/how-do-i-create-a-new-instance-of-a-collection/29751269?noredirect=1#comment47637139_29751269):

> I am trying to create an empty collection but apparently collections.emptySet() is apparently not the way? Google tells me to create a new instance instead... How do I create a new instance of a collection?

My opinion is **we shouldn't answer this question** in order to mantain SO quality and encourage OP's to make better questions so:

- I downvoted it,
- flagged as **too broad**
- leave this comment:

  > start here docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections –  Jordi Castilla

All in order to guide OP's to a collection tutorial, as the question itself notes (IMHO) a lack of understanding the basis or even investigating a bit.

Then, few minutes after, appeared this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751269/3850595)

**NOTE THE END OF THE ANSWER**

> **In the future, please refer to the documentation first.**

As I'm not agree with that, I left this comment on Luiggi's answer:

> don't encourage this questions with answers.... :( –  Jordi Castilla 48 mins ago

Then, discussion started:

> **Luiggi:** @JordiCastilla if you read the question, OP's mainly asking why Collections#emptySet won't work as expected. And IMHO the names of those methods are confusing, by the way :), I think they should be Collections#emptyImmutableXyz. –  Luiggi Mendoza 46 mins ago
>
> **Jordi:** *I am trying to create an empty collection but apparently collections.emptySet() is apparently not the way?* this means OP didn't take any effort of reading about Collections either Java basic object management. –  Jordi Castilla 43 mins ago
>
> **Luiggi:** @JordiCastilla I know, and sadly there's lot of people that won't and comments won't make them do that either. So, you can choose to help OP with a proper answer or just downvote, comment and leave. I don't worry about earning/losing rep with this post, just solving OP's issue. –  Luiggi Mendoza 41 mins ago
>
> **Jordi:** solve OP's issue is to guide through a tutorial to start with the basis... code you posted will solve OP's concrete question? YES but I bet OP's wont understand what he is doing. PS: i either worry about losing rep's with this question, I'm worried about SO quality. –  Jordi Castilla 31 mins ago
>
> **Luiggi:** @JordiCastilla I'm worried too, but I don't see you contributing either. And that's not a dup q/a, read it well. If you feel this is a bad q/a, create a question on meta about it. –  Luiggi Mendoza 30 mins ago
>
> **Jordi:** Of course you won't see me contributing with OP here, I'm doing it by giving you my opinion... And... think about why a question has 5 downvotes and if it's me or you who must create a meta post to defend position –  Jordi Castilla 8 mins ago
>
> **Luiggi:** @JordiCastilla whatever, I'm not arguing here in comments w/you anymore. –  Luiggi Mendoza 1 min ago

As Luiggi has much more reputation and experience in SO than me, maybe I misunderstood some part of asking good quality questions, and flag bad quality ones or maybe the question or the OP's intention itselfs...

What do you think?

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding your first comment, it's argumentative. If you think a question is off-topic, then flag/vote to close. Your comment just leads to a discussion that shouldn't happen on a post.

Comment: You are certainly entitled to your opinion and you are not the only one that thinks that way. But Luiggi is too and he's not alone either, nor is he discouraged by any formal "rules". You must realize that the outcome of this discussion was predictable, just use your vote to express your opinion.  If you see bad Q+A that you think does not belong on this site then you can DV it.

Comment: see also: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't punish answerers because of a disagreement with the question quality. That helps no one.

Downvoting the answer serves absolutely no purpose towards increasing question quality whatsoever. You should be voting based on content not on some inference made based on the situation.

The question itself can be voted to be closed for a reason you feel is appropriate, or downvoted for a lack of research. But taking action against the answer based on either one of those decisions is not proper.

+156 [It is not okay to downvote answers to bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255460/1026459). -[Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts)

+220 [Downvoting purely because you believe the question itself is off-topic is in my opinion counter-productive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252070/1026459) - [George Reith](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/718728/george-reith)

+22 [I'm tempted to dispute your premise here, debate the whole "answering no-effort questions causes others unwilling to put in any effort to ask more no-effort questions" idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286236/1026459) - [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)

Comment: [I totally agree.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions/255861#255861) Attacking people trying to provide good answers to questions you don't like won't stop those questions from coming. It will only drive away experts who were just trying to help.

Comment: @BradLarson - I should have included that as well in my post, I had already upvoted it in the past and think your assertion is completely accurate.

Comment: Might you point out where OP asks about "downvoting the answer", instead of downvoting/closing the question?

Comment: @Deduplicator - The first comment which started this discussion on the post, and which led to this post. "don't encourage this questions with answers.... :( – Jordi Castilla 48 mins ago". It was coupled with what looked to also be a downvote.

Comment: @TravisJ: That's the OP saying he downvoted the answer to the (in his opinion, did not check) bad question? That's far-fetched...

Comment: @Deduplicator has a point. When someone comes to meta and says, *"Why did mods downvote me"*, our reply is always, *"What makes you think it was a mod (or any other particular user)"*. So it isn't really fair in this case either

Comment: @Deduplicator - I would agree with you, if not for the fact that it happens all the time. I do not find this to be far-fetched whatsoever, and the fact that it even led to a meta post is an implication that this OP wanted vindication in his choice. The downvote was an act of discouragement.

Comment: @codeMagic - 12 views, 1 comment, 1 downvote in the first couple minutes of the post. Sure, it could have been one of the other 11 people, but given the circumstance that is highly improbable.

Comment: @Deduplicator `@codeMagic` - Further, regardless of whether or not the downvote occurred (which I believe it did) this user still actively engaged in a comment thread on the answer to attempt to dissuade another user from answering questions. How is that proper?

Comment: @TravisJ I don't disagree with with that. I'm simply saying we can't know for sure so it isn't fair to assume in this case either. Not to say your "downvote" section isn't helpful here. Just saying we shouldn't make assumptions, no matter how probable they are.

Comment: @codeMagic - So you agree users should vote on answers based on content? And you also agree users should not punish answerers based on the questions they answer?

Comment: The first part I certainly agree with. The second part I've been torn on for awhile. Because we certainly don't want to encourage off-topic questions but that is sometimes a grey line if it should be answered or not. I don't think a downvote is appropriate but I don't see anything wrong with leaving a comment (if polite) other than it can obviously lead to this

Comment: I recently saw a user answer a question by starting out, *"This really shouldn't be asked here but here's your answer"*. So I commented with *"If you feel it shouldn't be asked here then you shouldn't encourage this behavior by leaving an 'answer'"*

Comment: @codeMagic - Well, be torn no more. Do not punish answerers based on question quality. Encouraging quality answers should always be a priority, regardless of the question posed.

Comment: heh, thanks :) I guess what I am getting at is punish, no. But discourage, yes depending on the circumstance. If it's a complete crap question then it shouldn't get an answer because it likely won't help anyone else. This isn't one of those times. Overall, it depends if the answer is really going to help others or just the OP

Comment: @codeMagic - Okay, semantically discourage and punish may be slightly different so I will try to be more direct. Targeting downvotes at experts for reasons other than the expert's posted content will drive experts away.

Comment: Yep, I never disagreed with that part at all. Discourage and punish can be completely different things. Again, it depends on the content and if it will actually be useful for others. But I think we agree, maybe I just chose poor wording at some point

Answer (score 10):

From my point of view:

- The question doesn't have a duplicate AFAIK.
- It's not off-topic:

  - It is not about general computing hardware and software.
  - It is not about professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration.
  - It doesn't ask for recommended book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.
  - It's not asking for help to debug some code.
  - It is not a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.
- It is not unclear: OP states that he/she needs to do *foo* and tried *bar* but didn't work, he/she did some research (*Google tells me to create a new instance instead*) and posts that he/she doesn't know how to do it.
- It's not too broad, it has a concrete answer.
- It's not primarily opinion based, since it has a concrete answer.

So, I don't find any reason to close it. The fact that OP lacks the basic knowledge of the programming language to accomplish what he/she's looking for doesn't mean the question is wrong.

Still, this is just my opinion. If you feel you should flag it for close, then do it. Let the community decide if this question should be closed (and deleted) or if leave it along.

Answer (score 3):

Flagging for moderator attention would be pointless, as a flag of that kind would indicate that a moderator or some moderation process needs to intervene.  That doesn't need to happen as community members could step in and address any concerns with the question.

The question isn't exactly off-topic, but it's not particularly useful either.  I'd personally opt to downvote and leave it alone from there.

Comment: They are flagging to close because they don't have the rep to vote to close.

Comment: maybe is not off-topic, but is a the question good enough in SO to be answered?

Comment: I always forget that, @bluefeet; thanks for jogging my memory.  I'll edit this response so that it's clear I was intending not to "flag for moderator attention".

Comment: @JordiCastilla:  Personally I feel like this question is incomplete; they want to create a new instance of a `Collection`, but that has its own smell about it.  I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but if I *were* to answer it, I'd give an answer similar to Luiggi's.