# Does the quality of an answer depend on votes if it is marked as the correct answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, answer-quality

I wrote an answer on Stack Overflow that had a `-2` score in all (as I'm not sure about the total number of up-votes and down-votes) but it was marked as the correct answer. We all know that **low quality** answers tend to move us towards an **answer ban**. So my question is, now that my answer has been marked as correct, will it nullify the effect of the `-2` score in terms of determining the quality of the answer or, even though it is the correct (and only) answer to the question, is the negative score likely to push me towards the low-quality-answer region (to whatever extent)**?** Precisely, **is my answer going to be considered as a low quality one?**

Also, for your information, the question itself had `-5` score (plus it is **put on hold as too broad**) and where people were just referring to it as a homework dump, I cleared a basic misconception of the OP and in my opinion, what I did wasn't something that cannot be accepted by the community. Further, [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404746/how-to-use-input-method-in-java/39404882#39404882) (now deleted) I'm talking about.

Please clear up my question about this issue.

Comment: Why did you even answer that? That's ___literally___ the user's homework. That question will most likely end up being deleted. I'm not certain, but that may simply be counted as an deleted answer, for you.

Comment: Details of the ban algorithm are not provided, as it would lead to people trying to game the system. If you're worried about a ban, stop answering low effort questions; answers to them tend to attract downvotes on the basis that encouraging lazy people to keep posting is not useful.

Comment: @Cerbrus Just wanted to help. Plus, I didn't do the entire homework; I tried to make something more of an outline to make the OP understand.

Comment: @progy_rock: Don't encourage users that ask ___junk___ like that. With your answer, you're sending him a message that questions like that are "okay" on SO, while they ___really___ aren't.

Comment: Okay. I'll take care of that. By the way, could I just have written a comment to point the OP in the correct direction or would that also be encouraging laziness?

Comment: I wouldn't even have done that. This is a blatant homework dump. Downvote, close-vote, and link the OP to the "how to ask" page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *in general* the quality of an answer is still measured by votes and is not affected by its acceptance status.

As others have pointed out in the comments, the *actual* details of the quality-ranking algorithm are intentionally undocumented to prevent people from attempting to game the system. Knowing that acceptance overrode the vote score provides an example of how someone might game the system by simply having their friends accept their answers. These types of shenanigans are certainly possible with voting, too, but they're (slightly) easier to detect, and more importantly, the larger community can override the opinions of a few friends. Each account only gets one vote. A single accept should not outrule the general voice of the community.

Also, it is an extremely unusual circumstance where an answer is heavily downvoted, yet has been accepted by the asker. That in itself points to possible abuse and/or fraud, so the system certainly wouldn't want to ignore it. The only time this might reasonably happen is if someone asked for help on implementing something following bad practices, and you posted the answer they were looking for. The person who asked the question would accept it, but the community would roundly downvote it, because it's encouraging poor practices. If this happens to you frequently enough that it would matter to an algorithm, you are probably not one of our more valuable contributors.

In this particular case, as has also already been pointed out by commenters, you answered an *extremely poor question* (actually, you answered a question that wasn't even a question). Please don't do that. Questions like that should be downvoted and flagged/closed, instead. By answering them, you are only contributing to the problem. There are a number of users who are committed to [sending this message by downvoting such answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286230/how-to-deal-appropriately-with-answers-posted-for-obvious-help-vampire-questions). Putting aside [the merits of that approach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions), they do exist, and by enabling [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) [vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), you are subjecting yourself to their ire. Escape the problem entirely by only answering reasonable questions. Your answers are more likely to get noticed, and more likely to get upvotes.

Speaking generally, excessive hand-wringing about the possibility of an answer ban is not productive. If you are teetering on the edge, don't push it. Spend your time focused only on writing high-quality answers to reasonable questions. If you have built up a record of quality answers and are clearly a valuable contributor to the site, you are not in danger of getting answer banned. You don't have to worry about one or two poorly-received answers. These bans are only in place to prevent excessively low-quality contributions from getting into the system. They're not meant to trip up legitimate users.