# Downvote a good answer on an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, flags, downvotes

This question, [import data from dts to ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272297/import-data-from-dts-to-ssis), is both a duplicate *and* off-topic, as far as I can tell.

As such, I flagged it as off-topic (flag was marked helpful) and downvoted.

I also downvoted the otherwise-good answer for the above reasons, but I am uncertain that this was the best thing to do.

This question, [Is it wrong to downvote a good answer to a duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253735/is-it-wrong-to-downvote-a-good-answer-to-a-duplicate-question), indicates that good answers to duplicate questions should be left alone or merged.  Should off-topic questions be treated the same way?

Comment: Check out [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/)

Comment: I am terrible at using SO search functionality; it never finds what I'm after.