# Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, rules

Today the two following questions came to my mind:

1. Is it a user's duty to check whether a question is a duplicate before posting an answer?
2. Are answers to duplicate questions inappropriate / warrant downvotes?

These have already been discussed:

1. [User's duty to check for duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions) ⇒ **No** (but perhaps don't upvote his/her answer)
2. [Answers to duplicates warrant downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253735/is-it-wrong-to-downvote-a-good-answer-to-a-duplicate-question) ⇒ **No** (unless it is copy & paste)

**HOWEVER:** Today a user told me that it is **indeed** our duty to check for duplicates before answering, citing the [Stackoverflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> "Not all questions can or should be
>   answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to
>   answer questions which have already been asked and answered many times
>   before."

**That user has a valid point**: The help center clearly states that duplicate questions *should not be answered*.

So my question is:

- Does the Help Center suggest that it is indeed our duty to check for duplicates before answering?
- If yes, which of the two guidelines shall we follow (both sides have good points)?

Comment: There are few rules regarding voting and some people do downvote answers to common duplicates so you are always going to be "at risk" doing that.

Comment: I've figured out in recent years, there are going to be questions that are so simple, you have to this "this must be a duplicate".  That should be a hint to go look for one.

Comment: Even if it doesn't ring any bells for being an obvious dupe, I put in a token effort to search "site:stackoverflow.com [language] [terms...]" before answering.  It only takes a minute, and if more people did it we'd have more signposts for users to get their answer before asking.

Comment: "Save yourself some frustration" != "it is indeed our duty"

Answer (score 7):

I think there's a difference between something being a recommendation (i.e. *should* be) and something being an obligation (i.e. *must* be).

The help center says that duplicates "*should not* be answered", not that they "*must not* be answered". So, it looks more like it's recommended behavior than required obligation. It encourages people to be smart about avoiding duplication of effort, but doesn't punish someone for not doing this.

It's sometimes the case that the OP will point out some minor, but potentially significant, detail(s) that might be compelling enough to consider the use of slightly different wording in a question to be "different enough". It can be very subjective, especially if those suggesting it's a duplicate failed to notice subtle differences.

In those cases, I think the OP should be more explicit about why the new question is different to other potential/perceived duplicates. It might help avoid false positives (i.e. duplicates that aren't) and frustration to the OP, for getting flagged as duplicate, etc.