# Why do old questions with one line have thousands of votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) question from '08 as an example. The question is a one-liner. Does it deserve 12145 votes?

P.S. I know this post is kind of a one-liner, but I'm not saying they don't deserve the votes, I'm simply interested why they get so many votes.

Comment: Because they've been on the site for more than a decade, and accumulated millions of views. And although they are short, many users found them useful.

Comment: The funny thing about that sort of Question is that it "does not show any research effort". I think if it had been asked today, it would have been heavily downvoted and likely also close voted and delete voted within the first day.

Comment: @Scratte because today it would be a duplicate of that old Q&A. Back then it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I've seen people post that kind of question these days and then they get closed in a couple minutes.

Comment: *"Does it deserve 12145 votes?"* - 12190 individuals decided that it deserved their **one** upvote and 43 individuals decided that it deserved their one downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a technology is new and not yet mainstream, as Git was in 2008, many people want to learn it but cannot find resources that "speak" to them. For example, when I wanted to learn [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) in the year 2000, I found the book [Core JFC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013090581X) that really helped me learn it. However my boss at the time preferred the book [Java Swing](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-swing-2nd/0596004087/) which I found to be incomprehensible. Point is that each person learns differently. I don't even remember how I found that book. And that's the other point. People have difficulty finding resources because the search terms they use aren't providing the resources to help them.

Then there's SO where you can ask **anything**. You don't have to search for hours. And you get an answer to your question. And then someone else with the same question finds yours, because he had the exact same question as you and searched for it and found yours. And so he up-votes the question because he is saying to himself, "Exactly what I wanted to ask. And I understand the answer."

If you look at the the date of these "one-liner" questions that have thousands of up-votes, you will see that many of them were posted in the early days of SO or in the early days of some technology, like Java's [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) that came out in Java 8 in 2014.

Nowadays, I believe that nearly every new SO question has already been asked – and answered – because, in my opinion, the person asking the question either doesn't understand how the site works or is too lazy to search or genuinely doesn't know what to search for while the person answering the question is motivated by the opportunity to increase his reputation points rather than first checking to see whether the question is a duplicate. Please refer to [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Answer (score 1):

For a variety of reasons, there can be a bit of a [Matthew effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect) with voting - questions that are heavily upvoted tend to get more upvotes, and questions that are heavily downvoted tend to get more downvoted.

This is at least partially due to questions and answers that are heavily upvoted can be displayed more prominently, so they can get more views. For example, nowadays, questions that get a lot of upvotes can be promoted in the Hot Network Questions (for main-site questions) or in Hot Meta Posts (for Meta posts).

As to whether it deserves votes, that would depend on whether there were, in fact, 12145 people that were helped by reading it. If someone was helped by a question, it's usually appropriate to upvote it. That being said, this is a fairly basic question that many people are likely to search for, so it isn't all that surprising if people who were trying to find the answer to that were likely to find this particular Q&A (especially given its age).