# Why has the community's response to simple questions changed?

Tags: discussion

Almost 14 years ago, the question [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) was asked in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. It has since become the most upvoted question in the tag, with over 12000 upvotes. However, if that question was to be asked today, it would get a flood of comments saying *"Read the documentation"*.

A similar example is [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list), with over 4000 upvotes. If you go to any Python list tutorial, it will tell you. I found some examples here: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp); [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index); [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/). Now, people would say *"Do your research before asking here"*

This can also be seen in [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function), [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string), and [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python). These are some of the most upvoted questions on the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, but now people would say they are too simple for Stack Overflow.

All of these questions were asked around the same time, in late 2008, a few months after Stack Overflow was created. But, the community's response to these questions has changed massively. Why has that happened?

Comment: Food for thought: 1) How many users were participating on Stack Overflow before 2010? 2) How many questions were asked per day at that time? 3) How many total questions about any new subject existed at that time?

Comment: 'However, if that question was to be asked today, it would get a flood of comments saying "Read the documentation".' That doesn't match my experience. `yield`'s younger brethren is `await` and related `async for` etc. We *do* have some recent questions that are on par with the `yield` question you linked and they are very well received despite obvious shortcomings. The key part is that these were *new* questions at the time of asking.

Comment: Related: [Why do old questions with one line have thousands of votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401715/2745495) (and all the linked meta posts, on why comparing voting behavior on old questions isn't accurate)

Comment: Re *"flood of comments saying "Read the documentation"."*: Then they are misinformed. [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase) (in its various forms) has never ever been acceptable. Flag such comments on sight. They utterly failed to find the (canonical) duplicate (or were too lazy).

Comment: I think it's more of a general response to *old* things. People on Stack Overflow really hate the old. Just look at the many meta posts about nuking old questions because a replacement technology has been made. Which is exactly the opposite of how I treat the old; the older something gets, the more valuable it becomes. Because the rest of the internet WILL forget all about it, I don't know how many times Stack Overflow saved me (as a person who generally does not work with things that are hip...). There is kind of a disconnect there, IMO.

Comment: Agreed, @Gimby . Honestly, for some old versions of products, [so] (and similar sites) are the *only* place to find useful information on how it worked back then, as the syntax has been long since deprecated and removed, and the documentation with it. That doesn't mean that it's "ok" to continue using those versions (as a user you should certainly be aiming to update), but because the answer is *old* is can be more valuable as it's the only place that still exists with the relevant information (without trying to drive through the internet archive or something).

Comment: "*A similar example is Finding the index of an item in a list, with over 4000 upvotes. If you go to any Python list tutorial, it will tell you. I found some examples here: W3Schools; Programiz; GeeksForGeeks.*" something to note: the W3Schools article is from mid-2018; the Programiz article is from the beginning of 2019; the GeeksForGeeks article is from mid-2019. The Stack Overflow question is from 2008. I don't feel you're making a fair comparison or applying proper reasoning for how the situation is the same.

Comment: Can't speak for Python , but Geeks For Geeks doesn't have a particularly stellar reputation when it comes to its C and C++ content. Some days it feels like a quarter of the questions I see are cleaning up after Geeks for Geeks.

Comment: There's a bit of survivorship bias here - the poorly-received questions aren't around anymore to show up in your search results.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Because *they've already been asked*.**

Asking them again means you failed to check that, and thus ended up asking a duplicate question.

If you manage to ask a new basic question: great!  Hopefully it'll help people.  But unless it's about a new technology or programming language, there's a *really* good chance that it already exists.

Some people don't like these questions even if they *are* new, either because they don't think they're interesting, or perhaps because they feel that the question doesn't need to exist if it hasn't been asked yet.  While I can't stop these people from voting as they please, I'd encourage them to think about whether a newcomer to the technology would be better off reading the answer on Stack Overflow, or trying to find a reference to it in the middle of a poorly written tutorial on someone's blog.

Comment: I can imagine, if I am honest, that for *some* new languages or features, that such questions might be downvoted as they lack evidence of research. Many languages do have very good online documentation (far better than what was available back when [so] was launched), so an equivalent question of "How do I write an `IF` in language *y*" could well receive downvotes because it appears that the OP didn't even try to search the problem (something we *do* expect a user to do). Even *if* the question doesn't already exist for a simple question, we still expect a user to research before posting.

Comment: This isn't me saying that "Read the documentation" comments are correct though; but I don't necessarily blame people for downvoting a simple question where a simple search of "`IF` statement language *y*" in a search engine would have yielded the answer due to the documentation being found, regardless of if language *y* is a new or old language.

Comment: Ironically, just like this Meta question.