# Why was my question about React closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Here is my question about a bug that happens sometimes in React app: [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038475/problem-with-usecontext-for-setting-locale)

My Locale Context is not working and I need help. I described what I was trying to do, I've done some research as well, but I couldn't solve it by myself. The question was first downvoted and then closed but no real reason was put forth.

I tried putting the correct code excerpts that would help reproduce or at least understand the problem, but I'm still confused as to why the question was closed in the first place.

Comment: The closers apparently assumed that the missing `() =>` was the problem and adding it would fix it. Since it didn't, you should edit the question to fix that, and request that it be reopened.

Comment: As for your last paragraph, see [Why do old questions with one line have thousands of votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401715/2745495) Because they are _old_, and asked back when everything was new. As a tip, I suggest to focus your current meta question on your actual question on the main site, rather than on the comparison to the much older questions, because that has been discussed many times already, if you read through that link.

Comment: One of my pet peeves illustrated by this to some extent is missing code: `...`, closing brackets, or (not the case here) component function headers. It's not a minimal, complete, runnable example. Sometimes this makes sense, and sometimes I can eyeball or guess the answer, but the rest of the time I ask for clarification. Ideally, create a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537) so it's easy to repro and play around with. I understand this is somewhat of a full stack problem, but even without a snippet, it could be complete and runnable, with a package.json.

Comment: Answering a question is typically less of a "look at a few lines of code taken out of context and magically spot the issue" and more of a "repro the problem, then do the debugging/minimization steps that OP probably hasn't bothered doing yet to arrive at a solution, even if I wasn't exactly familiar with the problem before or sure of what the solution would ultimately be".

Comment: After all, without the reproducible example we out here cannot conclusively prove the problem is completely solved. Sure we can knock out our own example and test that, but every change we make is a chance to accidentally A) insert a new bug and answer that, or B) unintentionally fix the mistake and not give an answer. What's great about the *minimal* reproducible example is as you reduce the code, the surface area the bug can hide in is also reduced. Usually if you start the question asking process with a good, short example, you end the process before finishing the short example.

Comment: @BlueRobin - Author is synonymously complaining about their question being closed because a lack of a quality MRE and has done nothing to to address the fact their question is lacking that MRE. Their question could be salvaged if they were to edit their question to include that MRE. They have also received feedback their problem could not be reproduced with the MRE they did provide

Comment: Matt, you are welcome to reply to these comments or the answer whenever you wish.

Comment: Well, the Question (on 'Main') has now been deleted ("*for reasons of moderation*", not by the OP), ... which is a bit "strange" btw if it was in the process of trying to get it reopened (and the quality was not that bad), as it would eventually have been roomba'd 6 or 7 days later anyway...

Comment: @chivracq the entire user account has disappeared by the looks of it. Guess they did something naughty.

Comment: @Gimby, oh yep indeed... Looks like the OP "got a bit fed up" and simply deleted their Account... (without further vandalizing/deleting their other/older Posts, I checked a bit...). Well, fair enough...

Answer (score 8):

Per [Barmar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426326/why-was-my-question-about-react-closed#comment971534_426326), emphasis mine:

> The closers apparently assumed that the missing `() =>` was the problem and adding it would fix it. Since it didn't, **you should edit the question to fix that**, and **request that it be reopened**.