# Should correct answers be downvoted if a well answered duplicate question exists?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I sometimes see good answers to duplicate questions. I vote to close the question as a duplicate.

If the older question has as good an answer as the new duplicate, should I downvote the new answer?

On the one hand, the answerer should have looked for a duplicate question, but on the other hand it is a perfectly good answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but I'm also interested in a more specific answer regarding questions which are duplicates. I don't feel that was addressed in the answers to that question.

Comment: Apparently I chose the wrong dupe target. [Searching about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+duplicate+downvote) returned [Is it wrong to downvote a good answer to a duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253735/2821954).

Comment: OK, that does answer the question. And it also makes me feel more charitable towards people who fail to find duplicates, because I really did search before I asked this!

Comment: In the simplest terms: Downvotes, on answers, are to denote the answer isn't useful or helpful. Some are of the opinion that posting an answer to a (well known) duplicate is not useful or helpful. I, personally, can understand that view point as having many answers, to the same question (but different post), in many places can make it harder to find those answers.

Comment: Don't vote to give someone reputation points and don't vote to take away reputation points. Or in other words: don't vote to reward, punish or sympathise.